# Bash part of string without using chars in quotes

Tags: bash, string

So I want to get from a string like:

`q='"Something, variable", another part, third one'`

The part "Something, variable".

I could get

```
'"Something'
```

using `${q%%,*}`.

But how could I let bash ignore commas (or other characters) within quotes?

Comment: Does it have to be `bash`? Because this looks a job for a parser.

Comment: @Sobrique Agreed.  Doing this in bash isn't going to be fun.  In python this is already implemented (or php, perl, ruby, etc.)

Comment: I prefer bash, but other things are also welcome

Comment: Try `echo "${q%\"*}"\"`.

Comment: I edited your question to clarify that you want something like the first element, separated by commas, under the restriction that quoted commas don't count.

Comment: Your question is not clear. A good question pattern is: What is the input? What output do you want? What have you tried? What happened?

Comment: @richard - in what respect does this question deviate from that pattern?

Comment: @mikeserv hard to tell: “Somehow it seems to fill my head with ideas — only I don't exactly know what they are!”. It needs its grammar improving.

Comment: @richard - well, for my part, your first comment seems very pretty, but is *rather* hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple using `perl` is it has the `Text::ParseWords` parser in core:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords; 
use Data::Dumper; 

my $q = '"Something, variable", another part, third one';
my @words = parse_line ( ',', 0, $q );

#dump words:
print Dumper \@words; 

#just output first one: 
print $words[0];
```

Or to one-liner-ify it so you can use it inline in shell:

```
echo $q | perl -MText::ParseWords -e '@w=parse_line(',',0,<>);print $w[0]'
```

Which will read it from STDIN and print the parsed first 'word' in STDOUT.

(Or you could feed it in via `$ENV{q}` or similar).

Comment: `echo $q | perl -MText::ParseWords -e '@w=parse_line(",",1,<>);print $w[0]'` works for me. By changing the w[0] in 1 I can get 'another part' I need.

Comment: Is it possible to let the multiline script print also the quotes?

Comment: Yes. Change the 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "${q%"${q#*\"*\"}"}"
```

---

```
"Something, variable"
```

...works for just those two quotes by using the result of removing up to the second `"` double-quote found in `$q` as the literally-interpreted *(read - inner-quoted)* pattern string to strip from `$q`'s tail. If two double-quotes cannot be found in `$q` the expansion is null.

Also, if there were any characters leading the first of these in `$q` they would also be retained as well, though.

so...

```
q='x""'
echo "${q%"${q#*\"*\"}"}"
```

---

```
x""
```

You might handle that like:

```
[ -z "${q##\"*}" ] || q=\"${q#*\"}
echo "$q"
```

---

```
""
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the Internal Field Separator: IFS

```
q='"Something, variable", another part, third one'

# save actual IFS
_old_ifs="${IFS}"
# set IFS to ","
IFS=","
# split q with this new IFS
set -- `echo ${q}`
# restore standard IFS
IFS="${_old_ifs}"

echo \'$1\'
```

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: What you asked for: make `bash` ignore commas within a quoted string.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Within quotes, and across all "$q".

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe it through cut, specifying the double-quote character as a field delimiter and asking the just the second field be output.

```
$ q='"Something, variable", another part, third one'

$ echo $q | cut -d\" -f2
Something, variable
```